# Value of registry key is returned as null even though it has a value

Tags: c#, registry, return-value, key-value

i'm trying to get the value of registry key and compare it afterwards with a specific value if it matches this value. Unfortunately my method return a "null" value and i don't know why.

```
if (HelperRegistry.RegistryKeyValueExists("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Office\\Outlook\\Addins\\Connect to Outlook.AddinModule", "FriendlyName", "Connect to Outlook"))
{
   OutputHandler.ColorCMDOutput("Do this", ConsoleColor.Green);
}
else
{
    OutputHandler.ColorCMDOutput("Do that", ConsoleColor.Red);
}


static public bool RegistryKeyValueExists(string keyName, string valueName, string valueToBeTested)
{
    try
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName + "\\" + valueName))
            if (key != null)
            {
                Object o = key.GetValue("FriendlyName");
                if (o != null)
                {
                    string test = Convert.ToString(o);
                    if (test == valueToBeTested)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there, i went with a different approach and it works just fine. I added it to my original post.

Comment: If you found a solution to your own question, please post it as an answer. Also you can accept it. That will help other users in future

Comment: @AleksAndreev can i post also the code in here? Because i attached it to my original question

Comment: It may confuse other users, when you have same code in question and in answer. I don't clearly understand what stops you from edit your question, cut answer from it and past it to Answer section

Answer (score 0):

I went with a different approach. I'm using a different mehtod (i already got) to check if the valueName(valueData) exists at all and then compare it with the valueData that i want to be tested.

```
static public bool RegistryKeyValueDataIdentical(string keyName, string valueName, string valueData)
{
    bool returnvalue = false;
    try
    {
        if (RegistryPathExists(keyName,valueName))
        {
            if (valueData == Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, null).ToString())
            returnvalue = true;
            else returnvalue = false;
        }
        else returnvalue = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        returnvalue = false;
    }
    return returnvalue;
}

static public bool RegistryPathExists(string keyName, string valueName)
{
    try
    {
        return (Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(keyName, valueName, null) != null);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```